# Google Drive API 403 error from wget/curl, but not from browser

Tags: curl, google-drive-api, wget

I'm attempting to download a large file from Google Drive using wget or curl. I've set up a Drive API key to bypass the large file warning and need for authentication.

Putting the URL into a browser causes the immediate download as I desired (without my Google account being signed in). But when attempt to download with wget I get a 403 Forbidden error. Attempting to download with curl gives the following:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

The API key has no application restrictions. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Edit, original call:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FileID?alt=media&key=APIKey --output out
```

Comment: Make sure the browser isn't also sending cookies in the HTTP request. You can check this in the network tab. Depending on the browser, you can also copy the request as cURL.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code so that we can see how you are making this call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hassan. Copying the cURL worked.

Appearently what was missing was putting quotes around URL in the call to curl.

Edit, new call:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FileID?alt=media&key=APIKey' --output out
```